# Calling a Subroutine contained within the Enterprise Global Template from My Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am trying to call a simple subroutine contained in the Enterprise Global Template of Project 365, from my local project VBA module.

I have read elsewhere I need to enable a reference to the Enterprise Global Template in Tools>References, which I have done (Ticked VBAProjectGE reference), but it gives an Invalid Procedure Call error message when I try to do this.

I have also tried the below VBA commands within my template to try and call the GE Subroutine without any luck:

```
Sub Anything()

GlobalTaskRefresh

Call GlobalTaskRefresh

Application.Run "Module1.GlobalTaskRefresh"

Application.Run "VBAProjectGE.Modules.Module1.GlobalTaskRefresh"

[VBAProjectGE].[GlobalTaskRefresh]

End Sub
```

The really simple Enterprise Global VBA Code that I'm trying to call is:

```
Sub Globaltaskrefresh()

Msgbox "do something here when it works"

End Sub
```

Please can anyone point me to the correct syntax for this to work and why I am getting the Invalid Procedure Call error message when trying to enable the reference.

Many Thanks

Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Application.Run "GlobalTaskRefresh"
```

Comment: Fantastic It worked a treat. Many Thanks for your help.